# Remove duplicates of Data based on date by same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

```
SELECT 
    ,[ID]
    ,[Name]
    ,[Age]
    ,[CheckTime]
FROM Record
```

What I have now

| ID | Name | Age | CheckTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Alex | 23 | 2022-08-16 06:16:46.000 |
| 13 | Cynthia | 45 | 2022-08-16 06:16:53.000 |
| 14 | Kwabeng | 57 | 2022-08-16 07:54:44.000 |
| 14 | Kwabeng | 57 | 2022-08-16 07:54:51.000 |
| 15 | Asante | 23 | 2022-08-16 07:54:32.000 |
| 16 | Leticia | 98 | 2022-08-16 07:58:32.000 |
| 16 | Leticia | 98 | 2022-08-16 07:45:49.000 |
| 12 | Mercy | 23 | 2022-08-16 07:42:36.000 |

From the table id number 14 and 16 have been repeated but just that the Date is different, I want to remove one of the record

What I want

| ID | Name | Age | CheckTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Alex | 23 | 2022-08-16 06:16:46.000 |
| 13 | Cynthia | 45 | 2022-08-16 06:16:53.000 |
| 14 | Kwabeng | 57 | 2022-08-16 07:54:44.000 |
| 15 | Asante | 23 | 2022-08-16 07:54:32.000 |
| 16 | Leticia | 98 | 2022-08-16 07:58:32.000 |
| 12 | Mercy | 23 | 2022-08-16 07:42:36.000 |

I was able to achieve that with `FORMAT(CheckTime,'yyyy-MM-dd:HH')` but it has converted the CheckTime to string but I want the CheckTime in datetime format to help in filtering records by date

```
SELECT ID, Name, Age, FORMAT(CheckTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd:HH') AS [DateHour]
    , COUNT(Name) AS [Age]
FROM Record
GROUP BY ID,Name, Age, FORMAT(CheckTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd:HH'),
```

Comment: Why are there 2 rows for ID 12 in your expected results? What's special about Mercy and Alex?

Comment: that was an oversight my bad

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to retain the earliest record from a pair of duplicates, we can try using a deletable CTE with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CheckTime) rn
    FROM Record
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

If you instead just want to view your data this, then use:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CheckTime) rn
    FROM Record
)

SELECT ID, Name, Age, CheckTime
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method, I trying to show with one example.

We can use the SQL RANK function to remove the duplicate rows as well. SQL RANK function gives unique row ID for each row irrespective of the duplicate row.

In the following query, we use a RANK function with the PARTITION BY clause. The PARTITION BY clause prepares a subset of data for the specified columns and gives rank for that partition.

```
SELECT E.ID, 
    E.firstname, 
    E.lastname, 
    E.country, 
    T.rank
FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[Employee] E
  INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT *, 
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY firstname, 
                                 lastname, 
                                 country
        ORDER BY id) rank
 FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[Employee]
) T ON E.ID = t.ID;
```

[image]

In the screenshot, you can note that we need to remove the row having a Rank greater than one. Let’s remove those rows using the following query.

```
DELETE E
    FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[Employee] E
         INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT *, 
               RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY firstname, 
                                        lastname, 
                                        country
               ORDER BY id) rank
        FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[Employee]
    ) T ON E.ID = t.ID
    WHERE rank > 1;
```

Thanks

Comment: You should be partitioning based on the unique `ID` field.  But even if there were first name, last name, and country columns (there are not), this might not be sufficient to uniquely identify each person.  Even in the US, for example, there are 2 people with the same "Tim Biegeleisen."

Comment: Yes, We can. Thanks for suggestion. I will check this into my SSMS.